# Interactive data visualization for geo-data using Python

Tags: python, visualization, plotly

### Background

In some project, the dataset I analyzed is a bunch of features for different areas (countries or provinces). Presenting those data in bar-chart or choropleth-plot on the map is an essential work.

In the website [Our world in data](https://ourworldindata.org/causes-of-death), I found some great works for visualizing the dataset like the example below.

[image]

This web app contains the following functions:

- variations of the data by the time series (from 1990-2016)
- Change the data feature (i.e. population, GDP among the countries worldwide)
- Easily for saving and sharing.

I have known about the [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/) package, which has the similar functions.

### Question

I want to build a web-based tool for visualizing geo-data in bar/bubble plot (examples in Fig.2) using Python.

[image]

How to implement this function? Any advice/examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for Dash :

A Python framework for building reactive web-apps. Developed by Plotly.

https://dash.plot.ly/